# Task :react-native-face-detection:javaPreCompileDebug FAILED

Tags: react-native

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-face-detection?activeTab=readme

I use react-native-face-detection package for my project.its give error in below

Execution failed for task ':react-native-face-detection:javaPreCompileDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-face-detection:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/admiin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/7a7f5a0af6ebd8eb94f7e5f7495e9d9684b4f543/react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar.
> > Java heap space

I changed the manifest file and build.gradle file but its not working for me